# Are there different versions of the Captain Tsubasa anime?

Tags: captain-tsubasa

I recently started watching Captain Tsubasa online from the beginning again. It's been my favorite cartoon of my childhood. But I find some odd moments watching it again. It seems the animation is different in some scenes.

For example, from what I recall from my childhood, in the game between Tsubasa and Misugi, there was a heavy rain with dark sky and clouds which lasted far longer than what I saw online in this new version, or I remember specifically one of my favorite moments where Tsubasa hits the ground with his head during a game and tries to retrieve the ball again, but he can't focus - I remember his eye color changed, but in this newer version its color is the normal color.

There are a lot of these moments, which makes me wonder if what I see online is not the original version. Am I right to think like this? If yes, can anyone help me find the older version?

Comment: there is "Captain Tsubasa"(Shorter) and there is "Shin Captain Tsubasa"(Have a lot of sequel)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Captain_Tsubasa_episodes#Captain_Tsubasa